# ASP MVC AJAX return object and access in JavaScript as an Associative Array

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get my head around ASP MVC with using AJAX requests to the C# controller, as it stands; I am able to call my controller from my AJAX request. However I'm struggling to return the results I'm looking for.

Overall I'm attempting to get some data from the database and return it as an array to JavaScript. What would be fantastic is if in JavaScript I could access the data in a format such as `array["key"]` using an associative array.

However, this is what I am encountering with my AJAX request, Initially I call the controller from my AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/booking/getParks",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.data);
        }
    });
```

This calls my very simple function in my booking controller as you can see below.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult getParks(string stylesheet)
        {
            var parks = Database.Open("SQLServerConnectionString").Query("SELECT * FROM Park");
            return Json(new { data = parks });
        }
```

Now when I alert in the JavaScript AJAX success function you can see I call the `data.data`, this outputs the following:

[image]

Now, if I was to reference `data.data[0]`, this would output `[object Object]` and if I was to further reference `data.data[0]["id"]` which in my case I would expect an output of 1. Instead I receive `undefined`.

Now, I'm guessing that this has something to do with the way that I am returning a C# dynamic.

However, I am presuming that I am returning the Object to AJAX incorrectly.

How can I return the values so that they are an associative array in JavaScript? Or even a method in which I can receive the data and convert it JavaScript side maybe...

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: Alert json as string to see what's in it:  ``alert(JSON.stringify(data));``

Comment: What's the data type of parks? DataSet? Custom Entity Class?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - I Edited the post with the JSON stringify reponse.

Comment: @Tseng parks is a IENumerable<dynamic>

Comment: From the stringify result it looks more like you are returning a table or list if tables

Comment: Dunno which framework you are using for database access but did you execute the query? If DataBase/Open/Query are your own methods, show the code of it (at least Query)

Comment: Here is the Query... var parks = Database.Open("SQLServerConnectionString").Query("SELECT * FROM Park"); it's in the question i'm using WebMatrix.

Comment: Look at the Image of my JSON Stringify you can clearly see the query is executed as you can see the results are there...

Comment: @Matthew result is coming so what's issue coming? ?

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad how do I put these values now into an assoc array in JS

Comment: It is already an array @Matthew

Comment: Yeah but I'd like it to be a normal Associative array so I could loop through the array elements, this way i can target each element like arr[0]["parkID"]

Comment: But the problem is based on the return is that it's said that Columns, ParkID and ParkName instead of the actual values, but before I return the values they exist inside the variable... it's odd.

Comment: I don't know if you got this resolved but did you try, in our Controller action: parks.ToList() before sending it?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server returns data in DataTable format, you have to convert it to JSON or List before returning to Script.

Something like:(Using Newtonsoft Json package available in Nuget)

```
string JSONresult;
JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parks);
return JSONresult;
```